# is Power of Three?

Tags: c++, floating-point, logarithm

Leet-Code 326. Power of Three:

> Given an integer n, return true if it is a power of three. Otherwise, return false.
>
> An integer n is a power of three, if there exists an integer `x` such that `n == 3x`.

[Question link](https://leetcode.com/problems/power-of-three/)

My code

```
bool isPowerOfThree(int n) {
    if(n == 0)
        return false;
    double x = log(n)/log(3);
    if(x == ceil(x))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Why am I getting the wrong answer for `n = 243`?

I `cout` the both `x` and `ceil(x)` and both are equal.

Also when I do the log10 instead of log, it gets accepted but when I do the log2 instead of log, it failed again.

Comment: Floating-point numbers like `double` are inherently imprecise - can you think of a solution that uses only integers, instead?

Comment: `log(243) / log(3)` is not precisely `5`. (It's in math but not in floating point arithmetic.) To prove this, try `std::log(243) / std::log(3) - 5`: [**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c59a71ec5686eaea).

Comment: But when using log10 instead of log, I am getting the right answer and leetcode even accepted my code.

Comment: Sometimes you win, and sometimes you lose... That doesn't change the rules of floating point arithmetic... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Floating-point arithmetic is designed to approximate real-number arithmetic. A binary-based floating-point format represents a finite number as some integer scaled by a power of two (with limits on the ranges of the integer and the power).

log(243) and log(3) have irrational values and so cannot be represented as an integer scaled by a power of two. The closest value to log(243) that is representable in the format commonly used for `double` (IEEE-754 binary64) is 5.49306144334054824440727315959520637989044189453125, which is 6,184,637,367,337,933•2<sup>−50</sup>. The closest value to log(3) that is representable is 1.0986122886681097821082175869378261268138885498046875, which is 4,947,709,893,870,347•2<sup>−52</sup>.

When these two numbers are divided in the `double` format, the result is 4.99999999999999911182158029987476766109466552734375. Obviously, that is not equal to its ceiling, 5, so your test routine returns false.

The rounding errors that occur in floating-point arithmetic vary, so using `log10` instead of `log` may happen to get rounding errors in the `log10` and the division that cancel, resulting in a computed quotient of 5. Also, the library functions like `log` are implemented with varying quality—they might not always return the closest representable value.

Generally, you should avoid using floating-point arithmetic for tests such as this. Redesign your code to use integer arithmetic.

Answer (score -1):

An simple and accepted solution without using logarithm:

```
bool isPowerOfThree(int n) {
        if (n <= 0) return false;
        
        long int a = 1;
        
        while (a < n)
        {
            a *= 3;
        }
                
        return a == n;
    }
```

You should read the solution tab on LeetCode, there are a lot of interesting tips here. The Approach 3: Mathematics, common pitfalls section is about your problem.

Comment: Thanks but I did the same logic later on.
What I am looking for is the fault where it has gone wrong in case of 2 or natural logarithm but not in case of common algorithm i.e., base 10.

Comment: (a) Code without explanation is not a good answer. (b) The question is not just “How do I test whether a number is a power of three?” but specifically “Why am I getting the wrong answer for `n = 243`?  This post does not answer that.